# Not able to add remote repository

Tags: github, repository, git-remote

I want to push changes from my local repository to my github repo. I start with the commands giving from github quickstep:

```
git init
git add .
git commit -m "first commit"
```

and then

```
$ git add origin https://github.com/Svein-Tore/forrigling.git
fatal: pathspec 'origin' did not match any files
```

Any suggestions to what can be wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've to use `git remote add origin https://github.com/Svein-Tore/forrigling.git`

When you use `git add origin`, it tries to add the file 'origin'

Comment: I would also recommend to use `git` over `ssh` instead of `git` over `http`, as pushing to github with `https` is now only supported while using a access token. [More information here](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent)

Comment: Ups, I see, I forgot the remote word.  thanks Kevin